# Blacklist the Work tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tag-blacklist-request

So there's a [work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) tag. It's only on 7 (all but 2 closed) questions but we should probably just get the tag blacklisted to save ourselves future headaches instead of editing them out (and spamming up the front page). The tag applies to almost/all questions on the site (by necessity) so it really shouldn't be used at all.

Objections? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Hey now, plenty of people go to their workplace with no interest in working whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done.

[image: Burninated]

Please care for [the widows and orphans](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged)!

Comment: Danke Shoen Shog! Widows and Orphans are retagged, deleted, or on the cusp of deletion. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

I disagree, but I do think we should redesign/define it.

"Work" has two meanings.  It is either the action of performing some sort of service for compensation and/or other reasons, or the product of such an action.

tl;dr, Someone works on something, which produces work.

I think that perhaps we should pick one of these two main definitions and focus on it.  Say, the noun form.  Questions dealing with finished, deliverable work (like the first two currently holding the "Work" tag).

Comment: Perhaps "Work-content" ?

Comment: What's an example of some questions that should have this tag?

Comment: @jmort253 my apologies, i have been out of town the past week dealing with family matters.  these two questions come to mind immediately: [Number 1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11962/should-i-ask-my-project-manager-to-review-my-work) and [Number 2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/intellectual-property-ip-who-owns-the-rights-to-my-work)

Comment: Hi @acolyte, thanks for the response. Typically, a tag wiki summary and tag wiki body would describe what type of questions should be tagged with that particular tag. While you've quoted the definition of work, I'm still not sure I understand what questions should be tagged as such. On the first example, feedback seems like a great tag, and intellectual property seems to cover the second. I suggest editing your answer to suggest how a user would know when to use the work tag. This will help determine if there is indeed value to this tag. Hope this helps.